# Need to Rewrite/optimize Slow Query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have a query with following explain plan

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(applicant.id) as applicantCount,
    application.name,applicant.application_id,application.id 
FROM  applicant 
  LEFT JOIN application 
    ON applicant.application_id = application.id 
  LEFT JOIN calendar 
    ON applicant.application_calendar_id = calendar.id 
  LEFT JOIN application_category 
    ON application_category.id = calendar.category_id 
WHERE application_category.id = '886760e6d0b6ab306b0914a60ac4265e'  
GROUP BY application.name\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: application_category
         type: const
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 38
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: calendar
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 4
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: applicant
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2333634
        Extra: Using where; Using join buffer
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: application
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 38
          ref: eRecuitment_TestQueries.applicant.application_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: 
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Query takes 30 seconds to complete where tables `application`, `application_category` and `calendar` are master tables which have 3 to 4 records only. The `applicant` table has about 2400000 records.

Is there any other approach to rewrite/optimize this query?

#### Index details

- Table `application`

  ```
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ```
- Table `applicant`

  ```
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_abdul_test` (`application_id`)
  ```
- Table `Calendar`

  ```
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ```
- Table `application_category`

  ```
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ```

Comment: Does `application.name` have unique constraint (or values so a constraint can be applied)? Is there an index on that column?

Comment: Yes the names are unique,I had already tried that index but no change in query performance.

Comment: I see no index on the `applicant (application_calendar_id)` column either. And the last 2 LEFT joins could be converted to INNER joins (the WHERE condition makes it equivalent.)

Comment: Actually application_calendar_id and application_id have only 4 unique records so should i create index on application_calendar_id ?

Comment: I guess you mean that `applicant.application_calendar_id` has only 4 different valus in the 2.4M rows.

Comment: Yes applicant.application_calendar_id has only 4 different valus in the 2.4M rows

Answer (score 3):

The last two `LEFT` joins can be rewritten as `INNER` joins (due to the `WHERE` condition on the `application_category` table.

If `application (name)` is indeed unique, there is no difference if you group by that column or by `application (id)` or even by `applicant (application_id)` - the last one provided there is a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint from `applicant` towards `application`.

So, you could add an index on `applicant (application_calendar_id, application_id)`

and rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS applicantCount,
    application.name, 
    applicant.application_id,
    application.id 
FROM  applicant 
  LEFT JOIN application 
    ON applicant.application_id = application.id 
  JOIN calendar 
    ON applicant.application_calendar_id = calendar.id 
  JOIN application_category 
    ON application_category.id = calendar.category_id 
WHERE application_category.id = '886760e6d0b6ab306b0914a60ac4265e'  
GROUP BY applicant.application_id ;
```